Why is my bizagi diagram got stuck in simulation?
The payment task is 0 instead of 10.I'm trying to create diagram of ordering coffee, I expect payment, receive payment is 10 instead of 0. My gateway at enough moeny is 50/50 possibility. The order completed should be 10.

Please help me. Thank you so much.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
